# Rails generate number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails application report number whant begin with 1001,1002.

When iam create new report, report number stat from 1001..1002

```
t.integer  "reportnumber"
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also, why is it tagged with three different RoR version tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CreateSimpleModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :simple_models do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :reportnumber
      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "CREATE SEQUENCE simple_models_user_number_seq OWNED BY
simple_models.reportnumber INCREMENT BY 1001 START WITH 1"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :simple_models
    execute "DELETE SEQUENCE simple_models_user_number_seq"
  end
end
```

Using before create callback :

```
before_create :update_report_number

def update_report_number
  self.report_number = Report.last.report_number + 1
end
```

Comment: how can i add in method, like `before_create :create_number`

Comment: In model, how can generate  `before_create :create_number `

Comment: If you use above migration no need to create any before callback for this. If you want to do this with before callback then let me know so I will update my answer. Also in my answer I am considering that report number start with 1001 instead of 1.

Comment: yes @Nitin Verma, i already migrate my database, i want create before callback action

Comment: how add 1000 + 1,  update_report_number, can you help me

Comment: I can't get you. Can you please explain some more. or if I am understanding right then try `Report.last.report_number.to_i + 1`

Comment: i try `Report 1000 + report_number+1`it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59563/discussion-between-nitin-verma-and-faiq-adam).